# Run a script on every dom change and action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, backbone.js

I have a backbone-powered player which plays a list of songs at any given time and is fixed to bottom of the page. I also have several pages (working using Backbone Router) containing albums and songs so the user can click on "Play" on anything and the player starts playing the selected album or song.

I want to show on that album or song that it’s currently playing, even if the user navigates to other pages or searches for something (eg. one of the albums in the results is the one currently playing).

Right now, I have added a callback on player progress and it searches for `$('.album[data-id="..."])` every single second and adds proper classes, etc. The problem is this is resource-intensive and takes a lot of time and cpu power (css selectors are slow).

Is there a way to live listen for **every** dom change in the app and run the script on those changes not the song progress?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use `Mutation events`, which is introduced recently in modern web browsers.

For instance, if you want to perform an action after appending a sibling to a specific element:

`element.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function (ev) {
  // ...
}, false);`

Furthermore, there are more events that enable you to detect other changes:

- DOMAttrModified
- DOMAttributeNameChanged
- DOMCharacterDataModified
- DOMElementNameChanged
- DOMNodeInserted
- DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument
- DOMNodeRemoved
- DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument
- DOMSubtreeModified

Read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Although the performance of this events is depend on the version of the browser (for instance, Google Chrome seems quite faster with these sort of events) and also the client resources, e.g. CPU.

Comment: Mutation events are now deprecated. Use [Mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead :)

Answer (score 1):

You need an event you can listen on. Something that fires every time an album loads. If not, add one with [`$.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
/*in the code that loads the album elements*/
$(this).trigger( "albumloaded", dataID ); // second argument optional
```

Then listen for it with a jQuery delegated [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

You attach the listener to a root element and add a selector to make it delegated:

```
$(".rootselector").on("albumloaded",".selector",function(e,dataID){/*handler*/});
```

This will fire on every albumloaded event where the element matches the `.selector` argument.